# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (potentially due to code rather than memory)

Tags: java, out-of-memory, boyer-moore

Many related questions seem to point to a memory allocation or a memory leak issue, but trying some of the solutions suggested, such as running code with the `-Xmx2048m` flag for instance, does not resolve the issue.

This leads me to wonder if there is an issue at the code level, with some kind of infinite loop.

The first file I have is `PatternMatching.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

    public static List<Integer> boyerMoore(CharSequence pattern, CharSequence text, CharacterComparator comparator) {
        Map<Character, Integer> lastOccurences = buildLastTable(pattern);
        List<Integer> listOfOccurrences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        int m = pattern.length();
        int n = text.length();
        while (i < n - m + 1) {
            int j = m - 1;
            while ((j > -1) && (comparator.compare(text.charAt(i+j), pattern.charAt(j)) == 0)) {
                j--;
            }
            if (j == -1) {
                listOfOccurrences.add(i);
            } else {
                int shift = (lastOccurences.get(text.charAt(i+j)) != null) ? lastOccurences.get(text.charAt(i+j)) : -1;
                if (shift < j) {
                    i = i + j - shift;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return listOfOccurrences;
    }

    public static Map<Character, Integer> buildLastTable(CharSequence pattern) {
        // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE (DO NOT MODIFY METHOD HEADER)!
        int m = pattern.length();
        Map<Character, Integer> lastOccurences = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            lastOccurences.put(pattern.charAt(i), i);
        }
        return lastOccurences;
    }
}
```

And then I try to run it with the following `Driver.java` driver file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSequence pattern1 = "abacab";
        CharSequence text1 = "abacbabadcabacab";
        System.out.println(PatternMatching.boyerMoore(pattern1, text1, new CharacterComparator()));
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get when I run the driver with the `java -Xmx2048m Driver` command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3512)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3481)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:454)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
    at PatternMatching.boyerMoore(PatternMatching.java:40)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
```

Any guidance on how to figure out what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When and if you reach the condition `j == -1` , `i` is not adjusted - so by definition the loop will iterate one more time.   The next iteration all of the inputs (i, n, m) are the same so it seems logical to think the condition `j == -1` is reached again... and so on ..i.e. infinite loop which includes the `add` operation shown in stack trace.

Comment: @Gardener thank you very much. I added `i++;`right after `listOfOccurrences.add(i);` and that solved the issue.